# Partition list based on data constructor

Tags: haskell, partition

Let's say I have the following:

```
data D = A Int | B Int deriving Show
```

and I have a function

```
simplify :: [D] -> [D]
```

My goal is for simplify to create a new list where it will add up all values with data `A` (into a single value of data `A`) and keep the `B` data as is.

As an example, `[A 1, A 2, A 3, B 1, A 4, B 2]` would become `[A 10, B 1, B 2]`.

I know I can do it with foldl:

```
A (foldl (+) 0 [x | A x <- ll]) : [B x | B x <- ll]
```

But this involves going through the list twice looking for constructors.
I was wondering if there was a way of using partition, where I could separate the list into those that have data `A` and those that do not.

Comment: If you partition the list, and then go through partitions, you're still going through the list twice.

Comment: If I run partition and get list a and b, can't I just fold a and concat with b? I wouldn't have to pattern match the B data again with the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems doable if you're okay with always having the `A` value ahead of the `B`s.

```
simplify :: [D] -> [D]
simplify = uncurry (:) . foldr f (A 0, [])
  where
  f (A x) ((A n), acc) = (A (n+x),   acc)
  f b     (a    , acc) = (a      , b:acc)
```

Though honestly I think the `uncurry (:)` is a mistake here, and your final type should be:

```
simplify :: [D] -> (D, [D])
```

Comment: I've accepted yours because it more closely aligned with what I was going for. What I also noted from reading other examples was the use case of pattern matching functions with partitioning. This helps for more complex "simplifications", where I may need to call actions for multiple data types

Comment: Perhaps you'd want to lazy-pattern your second argument to `f`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need partition for that, just a left fold:

```
import Data.List (mapAccumL)

simplify :: [D] -> [D]
simplify = f . mapAccumL g 0 
  where
  g acc (A i) = acc `seq` (acc+i, [])
  g acc b     = (acc,  [b])
  f (acc, ys) = A acc : concat ys
```

Comment: TIL about `mapAccumL`! Do you prefer this accumulator to one that carries `Just (B x)` or `Nothing`, then have `f` do `A acc : catMaybes ys`? (`f` then becomes `uncurry (:) . A *** catMaybes`)

Comment: ``acc `seq` acc+i`` seems pointless -- are you sure you don't want instead ``acc `seq` (acc+i, [])`` ?

Comment: @AdamSmith yes, it's logical to expect `catMaybes` to be more efficient than `concat`. Lists *are* more versatile, though it's not needed in this case.